# Use Django's login_required decorator code inside a view function?

Tags: django

I want to write a view in Django (3.2) that allows any user to enter a value, and only after that has been submitted to require login (or signup!).  Something like follows:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.GET.get('val', None):
       # now login is required to do something
       # can we use the login_required decorator here
       # to forward to login, and then back here after login?
    else:
       # login is not yet required
       # ... a form to gather up 'val'
```

Can I re-use the login_required decorator in some clean way in the middle of the function?  I could copy and paste [its code (and the code of user_passes_test)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L38), but copy-and-paste seems unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can work with an inner function where we apply the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) to:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def my_view(request):
    @login_required
    def has_val(request, theval):
        # …
        pass
    
    val = request.GET.get('val', None)
    if val:
       return has_val(request, val)
    else:
       # …
       pass
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up mostly doing this, but putting `has_val` outside of `my_view` to not be visually nested.

Comment: @dfrankow: yes, you can indeed als define a "helper view" that has a decorator.